Should I load my derived data back into RDS or into S3 bucket after Lambda step function ETL process? Runtime issues
I am very new to AWS and doing an ETL using AWS lambdas in a step function where I:

Extract data from RDS table.

Transform the data across several lambdas in a step function, because the runtime is quite long.

Load the derived data back into the RDS as a new table.


The issue is, it seems like loading the data back into the RDS might take too long for it to be executable on the lambda run time. At least when I run it locally it takes more than 15 minutes (21 and counting).
What are my alternatives? I was thinking would it be quicker to save the data in an S3 bucket and just query the derived table from there? Am I doing this wrong?
The end goal is to use the data from analytics and whenever the source data in the RDS is updated the step function is scheduled to run so that the derived table is always accessible and ready both for analytics and for access by an app that uses the derived data.
Current code of the lambda post transformations:
Store the transformed DataFrame back into the database:
def store_transformed_data_1(engine, df_combined_prices, df_clean_flat_prices, df_wine_static):
    """
    Store the transformed DataFrame back into the database as 'combined_prices' table
    """
    try:
        with engine.connect() as connection:
            # Store the DataFrame into the 'combined_prices' table, replacing if it exists
            df_combined_prices.to_sql('combined_prices', con=connection, if_exists='replace', index=False)
            print("Data successfully stored in the 'combined_prices' table.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error storing transformed data: {e}")


If its timing out in 15 minutes now, imagine when you add more data! Ok so you have hit the limit with Lambda's & it might have been better to do it on an EC2. Never the less you can do a few things, upsize your RDS instance or batch insert into the ETL table in multiple step functions or increase the frequency its run to reduce the number of records. I dont think S3 will be much faster and that will lead to more cogs. IF you want to cut your losses create a Cloud Formation script for an EC2 and in its User Data / Bootscript install Python and etc on the EC2, execute your code then shut down.
